# Import tables from MSAccess to QGIS

Tags: ms-access

I'm running QGIS 3.4.2 on Windows 7 64bit.
I need to import periodically a specific table from several different MS-Access 2010 mdb's.
The database and path changes quite often, so an odbc solution is  not the right solution for me.
I tried the solution "Opening Esri Personal Geodatabase (*.mdb) using QGIS?",
downloaded and installed the 64 bit ODBC driver with command line ( / passive),changed the qgis.bat file and added variable names in QGIS settings.  When I try to drag and drop an mdb-file onto the layer window, I am still getting the message "invalid data source".